# iframe not showing all content on iPhone - works on all other devices

Tags: html, iphone, iframe

I managed to get this iframe to display and be responsive on all devices expect on my iPhone. Works everywhere else. Here is the code

```
<div style="display:block; max-width:940px; width: 100%; margin: 0px auto;">

<div style="height: 0; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 40%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">

<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" src="http://www.urotuned.com/smartslider/sliders/4/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
        </iframe> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Safari or another browser installed on you iPhone?

Comment: Yes, Safari and Chrome both display the same. Cutting off most of the iframe